# Expected number of two successive tosses is the same?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

An unbiased coin is tossed repeatedly until the outcome of two successive tosses is the same. Assuming that the trials are independent, the expected number of tosses is

1. $3$
2. $4$
3. $5$
4. $6$

---

My attempt :

I used a [formula](https://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-expectation)

The expected number of coin flips for getting $n$ **consecutive heads** is $(2^{n+1} - 2)$.

Similarly,

The expected number of coin flips for getting $n$ **consecutive tails** is $(2^{n+1} - 2)$.

That gives two ways to satisfy the criterion to stop, so stopping will be sooner, not later.

So,

The expected number of coin flips for getting $n$ **consecutive same tosses** is $\frac{(2^{n+1} - 2)}{2}$.

Hence, answer is $3$.

> Can you explain in formal way please?

Comment: The answer $3$ is correct : After the first toss, it takes $2$ tosses in average to copy the last result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple recursion:  Let $E$ be the answer you want and let $E_1$ be the expected number assuming you have tossed at least once (but have not yet won).  then $$E=E_1+1$$

as tossing the coin once gets you to the state governed by $E_1$.  But then tossing again either ends the game (if you get a match) or leaves you with expectation $E_1$ again.  Thus $$E_1=\frac 12 1 \;+\; \frac 12(E_1+1)$$

this is easily solved to get $E_1=2$, whence $E=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my python code to prove this question, and variations of it. You can alter it for the specific problem:

```
import random

SIMULATIONS = 10000
RANGE = 10

expected_round = []

def game(number):
    round_list = []
    for _ in range(SIMULATIONS):
        score = []
        rounds = 0
        while len(score) < number:
            choice = random.choice([0, 1])
            if choice == 0:
                score.append(choice)
            else:
                score.clear()
            rounds += 1
        else: 
            round_list.append(rounds)
    expected_round.append(round(sum(round_list)/len(round_list)))
    return round_list

number = int(input("How many consecutive flips of tails should lose the game?: "))
print(f"The expected number of rounds is {round(sum(game(number))/len(game(number)))}.")
```

With this program, we can enter 2 consecutive flips of tails, and we get an expected 6 flips. However, the problem is not only limited to tails, 2 consecutive heads works as well. Thus, we have to divide by 2 to get **3 tosses.**

Here is my crude code if you want to plot a variation of this problem (expected number of tosses to get n tails):

````
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

SIMULATIONS = 10000
RANGE = 10

expected_round = []

for num in range(1, RANGE):
    round_list = []
    for _ in range(SIMULATIONS):
        score = []
        rounds = 0
        while len(score) < num:
            choice = random.choice([0, 1])
            if choice == 0:
                score.append(choice)
            else:
                score.clear()
            rounds += 1
        else: 
            round_list.append(rounds)
    expected_round.append(round(sum(round_list)/len(round_list)))


x_axis = [a for a in range(1, RANGE)]
y_axis = expected_round

plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.show()
```
````